# CodedUI is blocking my automation scripts

Tags: c#, automated-tests, coded-ui-tests

My automation scripts are hanging when filling out some form details in a dialog window for IE-10.

The logging shows how the script stops for more than half an hour and then it continued until it failed. Other times the application is in an infinite waiting state.

I tried timing the get control operation but that doesn't seem to be the problem. But, I'm guessing the issue is around a COM operation like the Keyboard sendkeys or the Click action.

Please provide any troubleshooting methods for this problem.

Comment: Here's another reference https://code.google.com/p/selenium/issues/detail?id=5071

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This could be caused by the playback engine wanting to verify that the set succeeded. This means the click will do its job, but the playback engine can't verify that it did his job.

Can you try disabling the property verification by adding the following code:

```
Playback.PlaybackSettings.SkipSetPropertyVerification = true;
```

Comment: very accurate solution cause it worked now, thank you